# How to combine a list of objects to a map of list with a custom key based on a field value in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

Hi I'm new to Groovy and have been trying this out but could not come up with a correct solution.

Basically I have a list of objects that i would need to correlate part of a specific field and put it in a map with a transformed key. Given example below, I need correlate the values of the third field by the first four characters (e.g. key3,key4) and put them in a map. So all key3 objects and key4 objects in a separate map and combine them in 1 map with key3 and key4 as the keys and their original values in a list.

```
Foo[] foo = [
    ["field1a", "field2a", "key3a"],
    ["field1b", "field2b", "key3b"],
    ["field1c", "field2c", "key4c"]
]
```

into

```
    result = [
        "key3":[
            ["field1a", "field2a", "key3a"],
            ["field1b", "field2b", "key3b"]
        ],
        "key4":[
            ["field1c", "field2c", "key4c"]
        ]
    ]
```

So far i've been able to get the unique keys by using a combination of collect(), substring() and unique(), but i am unable to build the map properly.  I've used collectEntries() but it only creates a map of the object and not a map of lists.

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would really be a big help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `groupBy`.

```
assert foo.groupBy { it[-1][0..-2] } == [
    key3:[
        ['field1a', 'field2a', 'key3a'], 
        ['field1b', 'field2b', 'key3b']
    ], 
    key4:[
        ['field1c', 'field2c', 'key4c']
    ]
]
```

*Explanation:*
Group by the third/last element in the list `it[-1]` but only consider the substring `key3`, hence `it[-1][0..-2]`